# Регулярные выражения: только кириллица и цифры

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, html-form

Делаю валидацию формы (поле textarea). В поле может быть введены только русские буквы, цифры и знаки препинания. Текста может быть сколько угодно много. Проверку выполняю так:

```
regExp.test(data)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать регулярку? Моя регулярка работает, но только если введено одно слово

```
^[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]+$
```

Comment: так добавьте пробельные символы и знаки препинания в регулярку

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы забыли про пробелы и знаки препинания

```
^[?!,.а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\s]+$
```

Comment: `^[^a-zA-Z]+$` такой вариант не годится?

Comment: @axmed2004 такой вариант пропустит например различные знаки ;%$ или арбские, китайские символы, а это не нужно автору